# PdfSharp Rotate Image When Converted from PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg, pdfsharp

I Use latest PdfSharp package in C# to Convert PDF to JPEG. The Problem is When height is larger than width, PdfSharp Rotate Image Automatically.
How fix this?

Comment: Do you mean 1.32 with "latest package"? An MCVE would be good.

Comment: I use PDFSharp Version 1.50.4740-beta5.

Comment: PDFsharp cannot convert PDF to JPEG. An MCVE would be good.